# Cmake error : Configuring incomplete, errors occurred

Tags: cmake, boost, hash, cmakelists-options, orthanc-server

I was trying to build docker image using command `docker-compose -f caMicroscope.yml build` and I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at build/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/DownloadPackage.cmake:111 (file):
   file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

     for file: [/root/src/orthanc-indexer/src/ThirdPartyDownloads/boost_1_84_0_bcpdigest-1.12.3.tar.gz]
       expected hash: [af64830e570249076a0f024ae4654b59]
         actual hash: [6438b9ec0500dc361361d39f6a814b7c]
              status: [28;"Timeout was reached"]

 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   build/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/DownloadPackage.cmake:144 (DownloadFile)
   build/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/BoostConfiguration.cmake:106 (DownloadPackage)
   build/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/OrthancFrameworkConfiguration.cmake:504 (include)
   CMakeLists.txt:80 (include)


 CMake Error at build/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/DownloadPackage.cmake:124 (message):
   Cannot download file:
   https://orthanc.uclouvain.be/downloads/third-party-downloads/boost_1_84_0_bcpdigest-1.12.3.tar.gz
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   build/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/DownloadPackage.cmake:144 (DownloadFile)
   build/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/BoostConfiguration.cmake:106 (DownloadPackage)
   build/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/OrthancFrameworkConfiguration.cmake:504 (include)
   CMakeLists.txt:80 (include)


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "/root/src/orthanc-indexer/src/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". 
 See also "/root/src/orthanc-indexer/src/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log"
```

And this is the cmake command I am using `cmake .. -DSTATIC_BUILD=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/include/boost`

I don't know what is wrong, if anybody can help it would be great

I checked that I have `DownloadPackage.cmake` file and changed cmake command to this

```
cmake .. -DSTATIC_BUILD=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

but it's still not working.

Comment: Isn't the error message self-explanatory? CMake cannot download the file `https://orthanc.uclouvain.be/downloads/third-party-downloads/boost_1_84_0_bcpdigest-1.12.3.tar.gz`. Does your docker instance have internet access?

Comment: Yes it does but how do I fix it? It's not able to download that file. Is that what's causing this error. I am new to docker so I'm a bit confused